# search from the end of a line in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
id number primary key,
domain_name varchar2(100),
server_name varchar2(100),
create_date date,
create_by varchar2(100),
valid_from date,
valid_till date,
default_user varchar2(100),
default_password varchar2(100),
server_order number
```

I want to replace `number` and `varchar2(100)`. Basically, I want to only want to keep the first column. I know I can do it in Unix with `awk`, but how can I do it using a regular expression? Also, can a regular expression search from the end of a line?

```
(django_project) 16:19 ~/djangoPlay/theRightWay (master)$ cat /tmp/tx1 | awk '{print $1,","}

id ,
domain_name ,
server_name ,
create_date ,
create_by ,
valid_from ,
valid_till ,
default_user ,
default_password ,
server_order ,
```

Comment: Try [`^(\S+).*\n?` -> `$1,`](https://regex101.com/r/aJ5eK1/1) (with muliline modifier).

Comment: Or: [`\s.*\n?` --> " ,"](https://regex101.com/r/aJ5eK1/2).

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want, really, is `^(.*) .+$`. This will capture whatever's before the space (for use elsewhere) and toss away the rest.

The `^` means "start at the beginning of the line", and the `$` means the same for the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a simple `s/ .*//g`, which would delete everything from the first space in each line to the end of the line.